# need clickable text button for html code

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

i have banner html code, i need clickable text or button for that code, if someone clicks on text then that banner page should open.it means the banner code should be clickable text. below is my banner code, i need java code to open below html on click event

```html
<p align="center"><a target="_blank" href="http://buildmydownlines.com/?s=27324"><img border="0" src="http://buildmydownlines.com/images/468x60getpaid.gif" align="center" width="468" height="60" alt="Get Paid To Join Websites" /></a></p><center style=" float:left; margin-left:35px; font-size:20px;cursor:pointer;" > <a style=" font-size:16px; color:#FF0048; text-decoration:none;" onmouseup="document.getElementById('exestylepopupdiv').style.display='none'"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Click Me</span></a></center>
```

Comment: Why the semicolons? What is not clickable with what you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
<p align="center"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.buildmydownlines.com/?s=27324"><img border="0" src="http://www.buildmydownlines.com/images/468x60getpaid.gif" align="center" width="468" height="60" alt="Get Paid To Join Websites"></a></p>
```

Took out the semi colons

Edit: fixed links

You should make them relative.

Comment: banner code is working but i need just text image for that banner ad, if someone clicks that text image then above banner should open.. or how to hide one html into another html

Comment: To hide one html into another html and show and hide them onclick you can use javascript or css.

Comment: i am asking , i want to hide my above code behind of text image, if we click on image then it redirect to behind code..

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: no alexey, i want to hide my second image banner code behind of first text image, it means first image code should be visible and second banner code should be invisible. so we can click only on first image.. if we click on first image then my second banner page should open..

Comment: hi alexey, below is my code, but if we click on click me then above banner page should open, even that banner page should be hidden behind of click me.. could you please help me ..see above question i edited code

Comment: i need javascript to open above html code on click event